# How do I install and create a sortable tree in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

How can I create and install a sortable tree from npm command (npm i react-sortable-tree).

I am trying to install a react-sortable-tree but I am getting following errors:

```
npm i react-sortable-tree
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: admin-panel@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-sortable-tree@2.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-sortable-tree
npm ERR!   react-sortable-tree@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\child\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\child\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-20T12_59_52_880Z-debug.log
```

Moreover, I didn't just try to install this package, I tried many npm packages and got the same error message.

I have tried rc-tree, react-sortly react-dnd react-dnd-html5-backend immutability-helper memoize-one, react super tree view, @atlaskit/tree, react-treeview, react-vtree and react-super-treeview plugins but the error is same.

What I did in the morning is just by upgrading the npm version to 7.21.0 and node to v16.7.0.
May be after upgrading, application stopped working and installation but I am not sure.

following is my package.json

```
========================package.json============================================
{
    "name": "admin-panel",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.7.0",     
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "faker": "^5.5.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0",
        "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.2.0",
        "react-data-table-component": "^6.11.7",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.12.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
        "yup": "^0.32.9"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

My expected result is to develop a sortable tree using reactjs. thank you for the help.

Comment: The error indicates the issue; the components you're using are not expecting React 17.

Comment: yes but each component I mentioned above is giving the same error

Comment: Then each of those components are not expecting React 17?

Comment: Yes, You are right but the problem is we need to implement sortable tree. can you suggest some good library ?

Comment: Nope. If you look at the react-sortable-tree issues on GH you'll see there are a number of workarounds. I suspect there are many packages that are not yet React 17-ready or have issues with it. Maybe don't use React 17 yet.

Comment: thank you dave but we can't go backward to the old version just because of it. Most of work , we have in react 17

Comment: 2023 and this still seems to be the case.. can anyone suggest a sortable tree that works with the latest version of react?